# fastest way to insert lines repeatedly?

Tags: text-editor

What I am trying to do is add `#ifdef` and `#endif` before and after of `puts`. 
There are hundreds of `puts` in the code.  The string inside of puts is different in each case. I'm working on this problem with text editors like vim and sublime text 2.

Is there a smarter way of doing such task?

```
                                     #ifdef SOMETHING
puts("blah blah blah");    ========>     puts("blah blah blah");
                                     #endif
```

Comment: did you tried `substitute` command in vim ? Or even better `sed` tool ?

Comment: Thanks for the clue, I'll google them first

Comment: If the `puts` are all single line expressions, then you could do something like this in Notepad++ (and I assume in ST2 as well)... Find `(^puts.*)` and Replace All with `#ifdef\r\n\t\1\r\n#endif`. Don't forget to enable regex mode if using Notepad++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sublime Text:**

---

AFAIR you could use multiple cursors functionality in ST like:
">find_all<, `puts`, then `ctrl+shift+l` (or something like that which will give you individual cursor for each highlighted line), then go type required modifications (which will do exact same movement/typing for each line)"

Of course it wouldn't work that well with different indentation and stuff, im afraid...

**VIM:**

---

In `substitute` it should look more or less like this:

```
:%s/puts(.\{-});/#ifdef SOMETHING\n    &\n#endif/g
```

(though im not sure if something wouldn't need escaping here)

basically it means:
`%` - for whole file
`s` - substitute
`/first_part/second_part/` - substitute occurence of `first_part` with `second_part`
`g` - globally - meaning for each line found among `%` (whole file)

and first part is:
normal: 'puts(', then non-greedy (if you don't know what that mean - google for it, really worth to know) regex for any character, then normal: ');' which should match your puts'

and second:
normal: '#ifdef SOMETHING', then newline, then four spaces, then `&` which means 'found pattern' (basically this `puts` of yours), then newline, then normal: '#endif'

---

I wrote it of top of my head so please take into account that some things may need correction (shortcuts in ST or escaping some characters in `substitute` formula).
Thanks for understanding

Comment: find all, `ctrl+shift+l`, gave me multi-cursor.  I was able to do the task in like 5 seconds!! :D:D  I'll try substitute too

Comment: with ST its probably less typing and it is simpler to understand what's going on, but if you plan to learn vim (i mean like ever) `substitute` is one of those first commands it is convenient to learn (IMHO)

Comment: then don't get be afraid and don't try to put too much on your plate - it will all come at a time

Comment: as `.*` actually but yes, with that difference it is 'not greedy' also im quite sure this 'non greedy' notation is specific to vim (at least to regex engine inside, cause AFAIK in common regexes it is noted differently), look here: http://kooshmoose.blogspot.com/2009/07/vim-non-greedy-search.html